# Which Macs support HDMI with ethernet?

Tags: hdmi, internet-sharing, ethernet

Which Macs support HDMI with ethernet, either natively such as the 15" retina Macbook Pro, or via a Mini Displayport adapter?

My Samsung TV can connect to the internet, but has no Wi-Fi access. However, it should be possible to share my internet access via a HDMI connection and update the TV's software, right?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that this feature isn't exposed or supported at all. I've certainly never seen HDMI show up as a network interface. If the TV has an ethernet port, you'll probably have a much easier time just using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please explain: are you attempting to update your TV's firmware? If so, check the TV's manual - I'm pretty sure it's done by loading from your Macbook to a USB drive. HDMI over ethernet is a system built to provide  a digital television signal over two cat5 cables. It requires extra hardware on each end, and is quite likely not what you are looking for. 
If all you need is that internet connection, go to the "Sharing" preferences and turn on internet sharing by sharing your WIFI connection and checking the Ethernet box. Now connect the laptop and TV's ethernet ports.

Comment: Great answer! HDMI with Ethernet is new to me and I first got to know about it when purchasing a cable with that description. Your answer does help to sort some things out. I guess I'll do the update using a flash drive. Since I did not read the manual that was not my first idea. Now I took a look at it and they suggest the same :)